# Convexity defined by Karamata inequality

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Just as the Jensen inequality is used to define convex functions, can the Karamata inequality be used instead to define convex functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality) says that Jensen's inequality is a special case of Karamata's inequality.
Hence, if a function satisfies Karamata's inequality, it satisfies also Jensen's inequality and, thus, is convex.